# Locally typeset a polynomial division problem

Tags: amsmath, arrays, polynom

**Problem:**

Trying to locally typeset a polynomial division problem by using the package `polynomial`.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{l|l}
    & 4x - 2 = K(x) \\ \cline{2-2} 
    N(x) = 2x^2 + x - 4 & 8x^3 + 0x^2 - 2x + 3 = T(x) \\ \cline{1-1}
    & -(8x^3 + 4x^2 - 16x) \\ \cline{2-2}
    & -4x^2 + 14x + 3 \\
    & -(-4x^2 - 2x + 8) \\ \cline{2-2}
    & 16x - 5 = R(x)

  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Current output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

**The polynominal should:**

1. Be left-aligned as a whole
2. First part on the right (left aligned), second part (center aligned) and third part (right aligned)
3. Allow for text on each row on the right
4. Only have vertical line for the second row

Comment: What does "first part", "second part" and "third part"  in `2.` refer to?

Comment: @leandriis Sorry for not clarifying it, first part (8x + 0x - 2x ...), second part (-4x + 14x ...) and third (16x - 5 ...). It's basically the three sections below the first row on the right.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use a package designated to typesetting polynomial divisions?

Comment: @leandriis Considering that I have not been able to solve the adjustments, I would like to kindly ask to give the package `polynomial` a chance. How would a possible solution look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `tabular` environment and some `\multicolumn` commands:

[image]

(Red lines indicate the textwidth and won't show up in your real document.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\noindent 
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}>{$}l<{$}l}
                                             & \phantom{-(} 4x - 2 = K(x)                                      \\ \cline{2-2} 
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$N(x) = 2x^2 + x - 4$} & \phantom{-(}8x^3 + 0x^2 - 2x + 3 = T(x)                         \\ \cline{1-1}
                                             & -(8x^3 + 4x^2 - 16x)                                            \\ \cline{2-2}
                                             & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\phantom{-(}-4x^2 + 14x + 3$}  & some text  \\
                                             & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$-(-4x^2 - 2x + 8)$}                         \\ \cline{2-2}
                                             & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$16x - 5 = R(x)$}               & some text
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

---

With some more `\phantom` commands one can get the desired layout that was requested in the comments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}>{$}l<{$}l}
                                             & \phantom{-(} 4x - 2 = K(x)                                      \\ \cline{2-2} 
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{$N(x) = 2x^2 + x - 4$} & \phantom{-(}8x^3 + 0x^2 - \phantom{1}2x + 3 = T(x)                         \\ \cline{1-1}
                                             & -(8x^3 + 4x^2 - 16x)                                            \\ \cline{2-2}
                                             & \phantom{-(8x^3}-4x^2 + 14x + 3  & some text  \\
                                             & \phantom{8x^3}-(-4x^2 - \phantom{1}2x + 8)                         \\ \cline{2-2}
                                             & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$16x - 5 = R(x)$}               & some text
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a possibility to align the 4x^2 with each other and the 14x/-2x/16x with each other?

Comment: @kexxcream: This is most likely possible. However, it will either require manual adjustment or the usage of a tabular with a total of 7 columns.

Comment: How would I go about for manual adjustment? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @kexxcream: I have found a solution using some more `\phantom` commands. I have accordingly updated my answer. Hope this suggestion suits your needs.